# How to handle a hang scenario in perl? After accessing a file

Tags: linux, perl, file, sleep, nfs

I need to access a file that is in a nfs mountpath.
After I access, I need to see a hang. If the hang succeeds, then my scenario passes.
If I see a "permission denied" or if access succeeds, the scenario fails.

How do I hadle the hang? After hang, how do I exit/kill that operation and proceed with my program's next set of steps. I am currently doing this.
Can I do something like this if(sleep = 10 seconds) {

```
The subroutine takes the command to execute, file path.


sub access_timeout($$) {
     my $cmd = shift;
     my $file_path = shift;

     print(qq{Running the command "$cmd $file_path" on the client});
     # Here, I need to handle sleep. Sleep is expected case here. something like if ($result = sleep(10)) { success}


     my $output = $client=>execute(command => qq{$cmd $file_path && echo _OK_});
     if ($output =~ /(.*)_OK_/s) {
        croak(qq{Expected a hang, access should not work});
     } elsif ($output =~ /permission denied/s || $output =~ /No such file or directory/s) {
        croak(qq{expected a hang but there is response});
     }
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what command are you running that outputs `_OK_` on failure and hangs on success?

Comment: For hang, I don't have any thing right now in the above code.
I am planning to add a try-catch. If the access timesouts, I expect there was  a hang. Still testing this. Please advise.

Comment: The "client=>execute(command =>" command above is a  method to execute commands on clients.

Comment: I mean, what exactly are you doing such that you can only tell it was successful if it hangs? I can think of at least one application where this would make sense (adding a successively-increasing wait after multiple failed login attempts to slow down brute force attacks), but in most cases, it seems counter-intuitive and fragile. What happens if someone decides to fix the hanging behavior that your script is relying on?

Comment: This is used in a unit test. I will see a hang when the DNS server is down or not responding. So this "hang" would always exist.
The outcome of the above subroutine should be either : hang exists or access succeeds/denied

Answer (score 1):

Try [**`alarm`**](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html). This will throw a *signal*, identified as `SIGALRM`. All the rest can be gotten from the link.